Measuring logicality of programming languages?
I have a simple question of how would you measure the logicality of a programming language?
EDIT: I was asked to specify the term "logicality". Hence I will try and provide a stipulation. By "logicality" I mean that the programming language is in correspondence with the least amount of steps in logic to complete any given process on the processor or 'CPU'.
Now, here is my hypothesized solution: Namely, to read the data from the processor and analyze it in an inference model from the programming language being processed on the CPU, for a task or program in the respective programming language.
EDIT #2: I only stated this because of the recent interest in LLM's. I thought that with the sheer size of data from various programming languages, one could discover the logicality of various programming languages. I believe that OpenAI would be able to do this one day with their inference models.

What does logicality mean to you?  I think this question is likely too vague to answer in its current form.  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask for some tips on asking a good question.

I think it would mean that the amount of coding needed to process a program or task is in any given programming language in correspondence with the least amount of logical steps needed to produce the desired output. Sorry if it sounds trivial, as it may.

Please don't provide clarifications in the comments.  Instead, [edit] your question to flesh it out and make it clear what you are asking and what approaches you've considered and why you've rejected them.  Part of our goal is to build an archive of knowledge that will be useful to others in the future.

@D.W. OK, just added to the original post some thoughts via an edit.

Please don't use "EDIT:".  Instead, revise the question so it reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time, with all information presented in a logical order.  See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/657/755.  I realize this might seem very picky, but I'm afraid our site works differently from others you might be used to.

I don't know what it means for a programming language to be "in correspondence with" the least number of steps etc.
